# Can I reschedule a Non refundable international Flight ticket (AirFrance+Jet Airways; Barcelona-Pairs-India) with minimal additional charges?

Tags: air-travel, fees-and-charges

I'm traveling from Barcelona back to India in August. The following are my flight details, as I'd planned this trip long back- I'd gone ahead and booked a non refundable ticket (which was the only one available then as per my requirement). Now I need to reschedule my return and advance my travel date. Can anyone help me figure out how to do this while incurring minimum loss?

Date : 28th August 2015

> Air France : Barcelona to Paris
>   Jet Airways: Paris to India

Comment: What do the full booking details say about your ticket's changeability? Ideally the full fare rules, or failing that the summary from the booking confirmation?

Comment: Where did you book it from? Usually, you should be able to manage your booking from the airline's website. If you can change it at all, you should be able to do a "dry run" to see the charges that would be applief before confirming.

Answer (score 3):

Your ticket is non-refundable, but possibly changeable with a fee. So you probably can change your return date by paying the change fee plus the fare difference. You just need to call the airline office where you bought the ticket from, presumably in India (since you said you will return to India).

Now, before you call them, there's a bit of homework you can do. If your date is flexible, try to see which date is the cheapest. As I stated before, you will need to pay the change fee plus the "fare difference". If you're lucky to find the same fare on the new return date, you will only need to pay the change fee. On the other hand, if you pick a date with only expensive fares left, then you may pay a lot more than you would like.

Nonetheless, you will have to call the airline office or the agency in India to find out the exact amount.